# Sci-kit Learn PLS SVD and cross validation

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, cross-validation, multidimensional-array

The `sklearn.cross_decomposition.PLSSVD` class in Sci-kit learn appears to be failing when the response variable has a shape of `(N,)` instead of `(N,1)`, where `N` is the number of samples in the dataset.

However, `sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score` fails when the response variable has a shape of `(N,1)` instead of `(N,)`. How can I use them together?

A snippet of code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSSVD
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# x -> (N, 60) numpy array
# y -> (N, ) numpy array

# These are the classifier 'pieces' I'm using
plssvd = PLSSVD(n_components=5, scale=False)
logistic = LogisticRegression(penalty='l2', C=0.5)
scaler = StandardScaler(with_mean=True, with_std=True)

# Here's the pipeline that's failing
plsclf = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler),
                   ('plssvd', plssvd), 
                   ('logistic', logistic)])

# Just to show how I'm using the pipeline for a working classifier
logclf = Pipeline([('scaler', scaler),
                   ('logistic', logistic)])

##################################################################

# This works fine
log_scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(logclf, x, y, scoring='accuracy',
                                              verbose=True, cv=5, n_jobs=4)

# This fails!
pls_scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(plsclf, x, y, scoring='accuracy',
                                              verbose=True, cv=5, n_jobs=4)
```

Specifically, it fails in the `_center_scale_xy` function of `cross_decomposition/pls_.pyc` with `'IndexError: tuple index out of range'` at line 103: `y_std = np.ones(Y.shape[1])`, because the shape tuple has only one element.

If I set `scale=True` in the `PLSSVD` constructor, it fails in the same function at line 99: `y_std[y_std == 0.0] = 1.0`, because it is attempting to do a boolean index on a float (`y_std` is a float, since it only has one dimension).

Seems, like an easy fix, just make sure the `y` variable has two dimensions, `(N,1)`. **However:**

If I create an array with dimensions `(N,1)` out of the output variable `y`, it still fails. In order to change the arrays, I add this before running `cross_val_score`:

```
y = np.transpose(np.array([y]))
```

Then, it fails in `sklearn/cross_validation.py` at line 398:

```
File "my_secret_script.py", line 293, in model_create
    scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(plsclf, x, y, scoring='accuracy', verbose=True, cv=5, n_jobs=4)
File "/Users/my.secret.name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1129, in cross_val_score
    cv = _check_cv(cv, X, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
File "/Users/my.secret.name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 1216, in _check_cv
    cv = StratifiedKFold(y, cv, indices=needs_indices)
File "/Users/my.secret.name/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 398, in __init__
    label_test_folds = test_folds[y == label]
ValueError: boolean index array should have 1 dimension
```

I'm running this on OSX, NumPy version `1.8.0`, Sci-kit Learn version `0.15-git`.

Any way to use `PLSSVD` together with `cross_val_score`?

Comment: I'm not sure partial least squares is of much use if `y` only has one column. `PLSSVD` takes the SVD of `X.T.dot(Y)`, which in your case becomes a column vector. As far as I understand it, the point of partial least square is to find latent factors to project both `X` and `Y` on, where the latent factors of `X` are used to explain those of `Y`. In this case, since `Y` only has one entry, it looks like this reduces to plain old least squares. Using the transformer on that yields a 1D vector going in to your logistic regression, which seems rather pointless. You could just as well threshold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial least squares projects both your data `X` and your target `Y` onto linear subspaces spanned by `n_components` vectors each. They are projected in a way that regression scores of one projected variable on the other are maximized.

The number of components, i.e. dimensions of the latent subspaces is bounded by the number of features in your variables. Your variable `Y` only has one feature (one column), so the latent subspace is one-dimensional, effectively reducing your construction to something more akin to (but not exactly the same as) linear regression. So using partial least squares in this specific situation is probably not useful.

Take a look at the following

```
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
n_samples, n_features_x, n_features_y, n_components = 20, 10, 1, 1
X = rng.randn(n_samples, n_features_x)
y = rng.randn(n_samples, n_features_y)

from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSSVD
plssvd = PLSSVD(n_components=n_components)

X_transformed, Y_transformed = plssvd.fit_transform(X, y)
```

`X_transformed` and `Y_transformed` are arrays of shape `n_samples, n_components`, they are the projected versions of `X` and `Y`.

The answer to your question about using `PLSSVD` within a `Pipeline` in `cross_val_score`, is **no**, it will not work out of the box, because the `Pipeline` object calls `fit` and `transform` using both variables `X` and `Y` as arguments if possible, which, as you can see in the code I wrote, returns a *tuple* containing the projected `X` and `Y` values. The next step in the pipeline will not be able to process this, because it will think that this tuple is the new `X`.

This type of failure is due to the fact that `sklearn` is only beginning to be systematic about multiple target support. The `PLSSVD` estimator you are trying to use is inherently multi target, even if you are only using it on one target.

**Solution**: Don't use partial least squares on 1D targets, there would be no gain to it even if it worked with the pipeline.

Comment: That makes lots of sense. I knew that PLS produces linear combinations of inputs, but I didn't have the intuition to see that it wouldn't have any beneficial effects with only one target variable. Thanks!

Comment: I'm coming very late to the party. I only comment to point out that, in my opinion, the answer above is wrong. The point is that the latent vectors are shared by X and Y, so that the assertion "Your variable Y only has one feature (one column), so the latent subspace is one-dimensional" is false. In particular, it does make sense to run PLS on a 1-dimensional dependent variable. These notes http://vision.cse.psu.edu/seminars/talks/PLSpresentation.pdf shed some light on the topic. Please, let me know if I'm just confused.

Comment: Hmm, so my understanding of PLS is something like "find a projection of Y that is well predictable by X". Maybe that is the wrong notion. But if it is the right notion, then projecting a 1D Y simply amounts to multiplying this one column with a (hopefully non-zero) number, which can be absorbed into the predictor from the X side, yielding linear regression. I think there might be a bunch of different versions of this out there, a whole zoology filling the spectrum between PLS and CCA and regression, so we might not be talking about the same thing.